# Unable to dismiss alert with TailwindCSS React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

I have the following in [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-serl5o?file=/src/components/Homepage.js)

```
import React from "react";

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
  <>

  <h1>Welcome to Ticket Management System. </h1>
  <div id="alert-border-1" class="flex p-4 mb-4 bg-blue-100 border-t-4 border-blue-500 dark:bg-blue-200" role="alert">
    <svg class="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 text-blue-700" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-blue-700">
      A simple info alert with an <a href="#" class="font-semibold underline hover:text-blue-800">example link</a>. Give it a click if you like.
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-blue-100 dark:bg-blue-200 text-blue-500 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 p-1.5 hover:bg-blue-200 dark:hover:bg-blue-300 inline-flex h-8 w-8" data-dismiss-target="#alert-border-1" aria-label="Close">
      <span class="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </button>
</div>
  </>
  );
}
```

When you click on the "x" button to dismiss the alert it doesn't dismiss, though it does have "data-dismiss-target" set. I copied and pasted the example from [FlowBite](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/alerts/). Theirs works but mine doesn't. Why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it requires `flowbite.js` to handle this, you can see `Requires Flowbite JS` tag above its title.
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.5/dist/flowbite.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="alert-1" class="flex p-4 mb-4 bg-blue-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-blue-200" role="alert">
      <svg
        aria-hidden="true"
        class="flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 text-blue-700 dark:text-blue-800"
        fill="currentColor"
        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z"
          clip-rule="evenodd"
        ></path>
      </svg>
      <span class="sr-only">Info</span>
      <div class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-blue-700 dark:text-blue-800">
        A simple info alert with an
        <a href="#" class="font-semibold underline hover:text-blue-800 dark:hover:text-blue-900">example link</a>. Give
        it a click if you like.
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="ml-auto -mx-1.5 -my-1.5 bg-blue-100 text-blue-500 rounded-lg focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 p-1.5 hover:bg-blue-200 inline-flex h-8 w-8 dark:bg-blue-200 dark:text-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-300"
        data-dismiss-target="#alert-1"
        aria-label="Close"
      >
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        <svg
          aria-hidden="true"
          class="w-5 h-5"
          fill="currentColor"
          viewBox="0 0 20 20"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
            clip-rule="evenodd"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.5/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```